# How to mock getFormValues for redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-form

I am using the following code to test my action creator. Because my action creator uses store state, I need to mock the `getFormValues` and `isValid`. However, it will throw

> TypeError: (0 , _reduxForm.getFormValues)(...) is not a function.

Can anyone help me with this?

```js
import * as reduxForm from 'redux-form';
it('creates SAVE_PROPERTY when saving a property', () => {
  reduxForm.getFormValues = jest.fn(() => ({ field1: 'test', field2: 'test2' }));
  reduxForm.isValid = jest.fn(() => false);

  store.dispatch(saveProperty(1));
  expect(store.getActions()).toMatchSnapshot();
  reduxForm.getFormValues.mockRestore();
  reduxForm.isValid.mockRestore();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking this for a long time, I got a solution. Hope it can help others

```
it("creates SAVE_PROPERTY when saving a property and form values are missing", () => {
    reduxForm.getFormValues = jest.fn(() => () => ({
      field1: "test",
      field2: "test2"
    }));
    reduxForm.isValid = jest.fn(() => () => false);

    store.dispatch(saveProperty(1));
    expect(store.getActions()).toMatchSnapshot();
    reduxForm.getFormValues.mockRestore();
    reduxForm.isValid.mockRestore();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.mock('redux-form', () => ({
  getFormValues: jest.fn(() => () => mockWorkActivityFormValues),
}));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.